# Laravel - seed Data for categories

Tags: php, arrays, database, laravel, eloquent

I'm currently got stuck with the following: I'm trying to implement a catgeory system to my app. Therefore, I need about 100-200 categories with some "parent categories". So I want to create two tables: Category, Subcategory. The category table holds the parent categories, the subcategories are the subcategory of those, pointing to the primary key of the parent category. Here's what I mean with the category thing:

Parent Category: Clothing

Subcategory: Woman Shoes

Subcategory: Men's Shirts

Subcategory: Jeans

Parent Category: Handys

Subcategory: Smartphones

Subcategory: PDA's

Subcategory: Smartwatches

and so on.

What I tried is this:

```
 $categories = array(['name' => 'Clothing'], ['name' => 'Handy']);
        $sub_categories = array(
            'Clothing' => ['name' => ' Woman Shoes '], ['name' => 'Men\'s Shirts'],
            'Handy' => ['name' => ' Smartphones '], ['name' => 'Smartwatches ']
        );


        foreach($categories as $category)
        {
            $category = Category::create($category);
        foreach ($sub_categories as $sub_category)
        {
            $active = $sub_category[$category->name];
            $active['parent_id'] = $categories->id;
            SubCategory::create($active);
        }
    }
```

But I'm getting the error (when seeding) `index undefined: clothing`, guessing it's because of that part: `$sub_category[$category->name];`... But how can I do it better? Or how can I get this working?

I also tried that (in the inner foreach):

```
 $subcategory = new Subcategory();
 $subcategory->name = $sub_category['name'];
 $subcategory->parent_id = $category['id'];
 $subcategory->save();
```

This way, there are no errors, but every parent category has every subcategory, so I don't look for the subcategories parents.

How can I get what I want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've tested this and it works fine:

```
$data = [
    'Clothing' => ['Woman Shoes', 'Men\'s Shirts'],
    'Handy' => ['Smartphones', 'Smartwatches ']
];

foreach ($data as $category => $subCategories)
{
    $id = Category::create(['name' => $category])->id;

    foreach ($subCategories as $subCategory) {
        SubCategory::create([
            'parent_id' => $id,
            'name' => $subCategory
        ]);
    }
}
```

Don't forget to add all fields to `$fillable` since you're using `create()` method.

Comment: Okay, whats the answer now? Change the last line to your provided code? Same error, undefined index...

Comment: I've updated my code. It will work for you and it's more readable.

Comment: Yes, this works fine. I now use     protected $guarded = ['id'];
as everything else should be mass assignable.

Answer (score 1):

You should take a use of Laravel Relationships...

Here the relationship between Category and SubCategory is `One to Many`, so you can create a relationship like this.

```
// App\Models\Category Model
public function sub_categories() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\SubCategory');
}

// App\Models\SubCategory Model
public function category() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Category');
}

foreach($categories as $category_arr) {
    $cat = Category::create($category_arr);
    foreach($sub_categories[$category_arr['name']] as $sub_arr) {
        $sub_cat_obj_arr[] = new SubCategory($sub_arr);
    }
    $cat->sub_categories()->saveMany($sub_cat_obj_arr);
}
```

Hope this helps to solve your problem in a Laravel Way

Comment: What would be the way to use this in my case? Just the same definitions on top and then the two functions plus the `foreach`?

Comment: [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError]
  Type error: Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasOneOrMany::save() must be an instance of
   Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model, boolean given

Comment: Type error: Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model::__construct() must be of the type array, string given

Comment: Is the change you made right? Subcategory belongsTo itself?

Comment: No thats my bad, SubCategory belongs to Categpry, nice catch

Comment: Just changed that back, but still getting the error I said (Argument must be of the type array, string given), it says in this line: ´$sub_cat_obj_arr[] = new Subcategory($sub_arr);´

Comment: @user5638730 Whats the value in $sub_arr?

Comment: echo $sub_arr; prints out "Woman shoes", so thats a string obviously....

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127551/discussion-between-user5638730-and-saumya-rastogi).